# Find word sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to check if there are sequences of words in a text looking in a list of words:

> word_list = "never", "not", "buy", "here", "again", "more", "hello", "not", "will", "table"
>
> text = "I do will will not buy more here"

**Expected output:** will not buy more here

But not:

> will will (repeated sequence)
>
> will not (incomplete sequence)
>
> I do (sequence with very small words)

My script:

```
word_list = "never", "not", "buy", "here", "again", "more", "hello", "not", "will"
text = "I do will will not buy more here"

text = text.split(" ")

sequences = []
counter = 0
for words in text:
    for word in word_list:
        if word in text:
            sequences.append(word)
            counter =+ counter
        
            # to avoid meaningless sequences like (incomplete sequence): "will not", "I will", "more here"...
            sequences_two_words = []
            for sequence in sequences:
                if len(sequence) <= 2:
                    pass
                else:
                    sequences_two_words.append(sequence)
                
            # to avoid sequences like (repeated sequence): "will will"
            sequences_not_repeat = []
            for not_repeat in sequences_two_words:
                if not_repeat[0] == not_repeat[1]:
                    pass
                else:
                    sequences_not_repeat.append(not_repeat)

            # to avoid sequences like (sequence with very small words): "I do"
            sequences_not_little = []
            for little_len in sequences_not_repeat:
                if len(little_len[1]) <= 2:
                    pass
                else:
                    sequences_not_little.append(little_len)


    print(sequences_not_little)
```

My output:

> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word_list = "never", "not", "buy", "here", "again", "more", "hello", "not", "will", "table"

text = "I do will will not buy more here"

text_split = text.lower().split(" ")

sequences = []
sequence = ()
prev = False

for word in text_split:
    if word in word_list:
        # len(word) > 2 removes: I do (sequence with very small words)
        # prev != word removes: [will will (repeated sequence)]

        if len(word) > 2 and prev != word: 
            sequence += (word, )
    else:
        if len(sequence) > 2: # removes: will not (incomplete sequence)

            sequences.append(sequence)
            sequence = ()

    prev = word

if len(sequence) > 2:
    sequences.append(sequence)

print(sequences) # array sequences you want
```